# E(RPM) vs E(CTR)*E(RPC)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I am working on a problem of advertising industry to estimate RPM(Revenue per 1000 impressions, https://techterms.com/definition/rpm). Revenue depends on CTR( ad click rate) and RPC( revenue per ad click). Which is the better way to model the problem amoung the below 2 method or is there any other way to model this problem.

1. compute E(RPM|feature1, feature2.....)
2. compute E(CTR|feature1, feature2.....) and E(RPC|feature1, feature2....) and use their product as final estimator.